# Ubuntu 16.04 Computer shuts down at around 50%

Tags: 16.04, laptop, power-management, shutdown, battery

My computer shuts down suddenly at around 50% and refuses to turn on again without power, reaches only to Dell splash screen. Most probably this is a battery calibration problem, so I thought I'll calibrate my battery. But the real problem is, it never wants to go down let's say 45% and shuts down and when I plug it in and turn on again, it shows the battery level it was showing before shutting down e.g. instead of 5-7% it starts charging from say 45-50%. I checked my battery stats and there are discrepancies, it happens with all the OSs I have so it's not my installation problem. Please find my `upower` report:

```
    Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 16 Oct 2016 08:16:42 PM PKT (2865 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  model:                DELL JXFRPA2
  serial:               1314
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 16 Oct 2016 09:02:45 PM PKT (102 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47.397 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         51.6816 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48.84 Wh
    energy-rate:         9.6126 W
    voltage:             12.562 V
    time to full:        26.7 minutes
    percentage:          91%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1476633765  9.613   charging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 16 Oct 2016 09:02:45 PM PKT (102 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47.397 Wh
    energy-full:         51.6816 Wh
    energy-rate:         9.6126 W
    time to full:        26.7 minutes
    percentage:          91%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

[image: Battery from indicator]

Comment: How old is that battery?

Comment: @CelticWarrior maybe 1.5 years

Comment: Not that old, about half life. Have you used at some point any Windows utility related with power management, battery "health" or anything similar?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I don't use Windows, I have it but don't use it. I hackintosh and Ubuntu

Comment: Check for BIOS/UEFI updates from Dell.